# React Hooks UseEffect is not working on my cacheImage component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I m trying to fetch data from firestore and display it on my app, it work fine. However, it cannot show my image from cacheImage component. My cacheimage is working fine with another component (flatlist) but it is not working on my profile page.
It is the code I fetch data from firestore

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(type)
            .doc(id)
            .onSnapshot(
                doc => {
                    setLoading(false)
                    setDisplayData(doc.data())

                },
                err => {
                    setError(err)
                }
            )
        return () => unsubscribe()


    }, [id])
 return (
    <View style={{styles.container}}>

        <CacheImage style={styles.imageStyle} image={displayData.avatar} width={'100%'} 
        height={300}>
        </CacheImage>
```

It is my cache image component (this work fine in other page)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import md5 from 'md5'

export default CacaheImage = ({image,width,height}) => {

const [failed, setFailed] = useState(false)
const [imgUri, setImgUri] = useState()

   useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('image',image)
    _DownLoadImage = async () => {
    const img = image
    const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + md5(image)+ '.jpg';
    const info =  await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri)
    if (!info.exists) {
        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            img,
            fileUri,
        ).then(({ uri }) => {
            console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
         setImgUri({uri: uri})
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                setFailed(true)
            });

    } else {

        setImgUri({uri: info.uri})
        console.log('exist')
        }
    }
    _DownLoadImage()

   },[])

    return (
    <View style={{borderRadius:10}}>
    <Image style={{ width: width, height: height, borderRadius:10 }} source={imgUri}></Image>
    </View>
    );
    }
```

I m thinking it is because I have a useEffect in my component which affect me to pass data from an useEffect function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess you either want to use

```
setImgUri(info.uri)
```

or

```
source={imgUri.uri}
```

Since you're currently setting `imgUri` to an object, that's probably not a valid `source`, unless there's something in your code you're not showing us.

You also may need to add a dependency to the second argument of `useEffect` instead of an empty array.  I see you have `[id]` in your working example.  Without a dependency this will only run on initial mount and never again after.

Comment: Thats all the code for the cache component and for the useEffect i would like have a initial call only. I guess you may be right on the imguri u pointed out. As you can see i did try console log for the cache image component but it is undefined